# sfdx: how to force:source:pull customized values from a packaged globalValueSet

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

We have an unlocked package that defines a globalValueSet.  It is installed into our scratch orgs, and we will add custom values.  We'd then like to pull those custom values back into our project, to be deployed to other scratch orgs in the future.  The values cannot go into the unlocked package, as they do not apply everywhere the unlocked package will be used.

Of course, `force:source:pull` will ignore the globalValueSet because it is part of an unlocked package.  By comparison, the package also defines custom metadata types; when we create new metadata values for these MDTs, we can pull those metadata values, as they weren't actually installed by the package.  But for a global value set, any "customization" occurs inside the original metadata object/file, and so is ignores by `force:source:pull`.

I have considered a couple of approaches which we are going to test, but I wanted to see if there is an accepted or correct way to do this.  Approaches to be tried:

- copy the original `.globalValueSet` source file from the unlocked package repo into the project repo, customize it in place, and see if `force:souce:push` will push those changes into the scratch org.
- use `force:source:retrieve` to fetch the globalValueSet from the scratch org (followed by `force:source:tracking:reset` to fix the tracking that `retrieve` will break), and see if that allows `push` and `pull` to work.

Is there a better way to achieve this?